# Strange Audio Session Crash Report

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, crash-reports

Does anybody have an idea of what could possibly be happening here is this crash report?

This is a 4.3+ iPad app.

---

0    NFLNewsPlatform 0x00131e59 NFLNewsPlatform 577113

1    libsystem_c.dylib 0x30b1652f _sigtramp 38

2    AVFoundation 0x3659fbbd _ZL30AVAudioSessionPropertyListenerPvmmPKv 240

3    AudioToolbox 0x34f78f27 _ZN29AudioSessionPropertyListeners24CallPropertyListenersImpEmmPKv 274

4    AudioToolbox 0x34f79205 _ZN29AudioSessionPropertyListeners21CallPropertyListenersEmmPKv 240

5    AudioToolbox 0x34f78823 SSServer_AudioSessionDeferredListenerMessage 218

6    AudioToolbox 0x34f1f585 _XAudioSessionDeferredListenerMessage 116

7    AudioToolbox 0x34eb4373 mshMIGPerform 374

8    CoreFoundation 0x35600553 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** 38

9    CoreFoundation 0x356004f5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 140

10   CoreFoundation 0x355ff343 __CFRunLoopRun 1370

11   CoreFoundation 0x355824dd CFRunLoopRunSpecific 300

12   CoreFoundation 0x355823a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode 104

13   GraphicsServices 0x3206cfed GSEventRunModal 156

14   UIKit 0x37946743 UIApplicationMain 1090

15   NFLNewsPlatform 0x000a7c67 NFLNewsPlatform 11367

16   NFLNewsPlatform 0x000a7c20 NFLNewsPlatform 11296

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the inclusion of the AudioSessionPropertyListeners CallPropertyListenersImp, I would be looking for a case where you are setting an interrupt or route change listener callback function on your audio session, and either there is something bad happening in that function, or my suspicion is a related object used in that function has been released - perhaps even the  value passed in the userInfo.

I also wonder if perhaps you are trying to do something in the callback which cannot be done in a background thread?

Answer (score 0):

We've just been tracking a very similar crash.

Ours turn out to be as described here:

https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer/issues/6

In particular, MyAudioSessionInterruptionListener (or the name of the callback passed to 
AudioSessionInitialize) and it's inClientData can not be changed after it's been registered, so the callback must always do something sensible even if the underlying object has been deallocated.

The solution suggested for AudioStream is to use a static variable, and make sure it points to the object that is currently interested in the callback, and never points at a deallocated object - the important thing is not to use inClientData.